# Test for convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Test for convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}}$

I test the series by this steps 
$(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n} = (e^{\ln \ln \ln n})^{\ln n}= (e^{ \ln n})^{\ln \ln \ln n }=n^{\ln \ln \ln n}$.

Then 
$(\ln{ {\ln \ln{n}}}) > 2$.

Thus,  $\frac{1}{(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}} < \frac{1}{n^2}$
and thus the series converges by the comparison test.
Is this work..!? are there some wrongs ..!?

Comment: Look [Nature of the series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(\log\log n)^{\log n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034789/nature-of-the-series-sum-n-3-infty-dfrac1-log-log-n-log-n)

Comment: Your proof is correct, provided you replace "Then $(\ln{ {\ln \ln{n}}}) > 2$" by "Then $(\ln{ {\ln \ln{n}}}) > 2$ for every $n$ large enough" (and one might even argue it is the simplest approach). Kudos.

Comment: @Sil Thanks, wondering why my approach did not work.